# cumprod() seems to give me a bunch of partially blank values

Tags: python, numpy, cumulative-sum

I'm a bit new to Python still

Here's my code:

```
np.random.seed(102)
mu = 0.001
sigma= 0.01
p0= 369
returns = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, size=252 )
cum_g = 1+returns.cumprod()
print ( returns[0:10] )
print( cum_g[0:10] )

cum_g[-1]
```

For some reason, if I run:

```
returns
```

I'll get a proper array that looks like:

[image: Proper array results]

But for some reason, running this:

```
cum_g = 1+returns.cumprod()
```

Results in an array of 1. and blank values

[image: Blank values]

It looks as if function tried rounding to the nearest whole number after a certain point, I'm not sure if this is actually the result or if I've made some mistake

Comment: You are running `cumprod`,  so the values evaluate to almost zero after the first few.

Comment: The average value of a normal distribution, with the default parameters (as you have here) is zero. So, as per @Psidom's comment, you end up multiplying values close to 0 with each other with each step, getting smaller and smaller towards 0. Add 1, and you get the result you see.